# Recover contacts from Microsoft Account

Tags: lumia-520

I lost my Lumia 520 and need to recover my contacts.
I bought new Lumia 520. How can I get my old contacts from old Microsoft Account to my new phone.

Comment: Have you created a whole new Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to enter your credentials in the phone (email and password) and wait for the automatic synchronization.

Look at this: [Synchronize contacts](https://www.windowsphone.com/it-IT/how-to/wp8/people/import-contacts-onto-my-new-phone)